# Regex to match string with hyphen sign between two numbers

Tags: php, regex, matching

For example, if there was this string:

`what is 4-3`, how would it be accomplished in PHP to check if a number minus another number is in a string, while not misfiring in cases like `you're pig-brained`. Is it possible to create such a matching system in regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple:

```
preg_match('/\d+\-\d+/', $string, $match);
var_dump($matches);
```

If you want to match all such patterns then use:

```
preg_match_all('/\d+\-\d+/', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```